# Applying medicine in mouth will invalidate the fast?

Tags: practical-islam, sawm

If someone have mouth infection and apply medicine in mouth and throw that medicine outside than it will invalidate fast?

Comment: Are you asking whether doing so while fasting is allowed? Or whether doing this between Maghrib and Fajr (the time one could eat and drink). An answer may also depend on the kind and ingredients of the medicine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes applying medicine in mouth will invalidate the fast because there is a possibility for some amount of medicine to be swallowed.

Comment: Please cite references/quotations from Quran or/and Hadith to your answer.